# How to create derived fields with mongoose model and save them

Tags: mongoose

I can't arrive a create derived fields i used Schema.pre method but didn't get it to work.

```
productSchema.pre('save', (next)=>{
this.total = this.quantity * this.s_price
next();
})
```

i used the method just after defining the schema